# User's data on cURL requests

Tags: php, curl

What the cURL sends to the request's address? The PHP script is hosted on a dedicated server. When I'm accessing the script, is it sending my IP address or the server's one with a referer? I was always wondering this.

Comment: It's sending the servers. It is not possible for curl on your server to use YOUR home IP address. TCP does not permit this. not the point of establishing an actual connection. Only the SYN stage of the 3-way handshake could be spoofed in this manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the PHP server is making the request, it is sending its own IP address.